# Transfer the product card to a new sheet when printing on the printer

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, vue.js

Could you please advise me at least in what direction to think about?

I have the following case. I am realizing a print template on a sheet of A4 (horizontal)
There are some product cards of arbitrary height (number of rows) and arbitrary width (number of columns maximum 8 columns), and as you can see on the screenshot, one block goes beyond the A4 page, respectively, you need to make a page break (page-break-before: always) and move this block to the next page of printing.

But I can't understand in what case to put a break before this block.

Counting the height of the blocks sequentially is wrong, I've already tried that.

[Screenshot of an example of how it should be implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6mXO.png)

I tried to count the height of consecutive blocks in the grid. I tried to count the height by rows, but with this approach the break occurs before each block, not before the desired one

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer without knowing the content. I would personally drop grid in print completely (though. again, depending on the content) and used something akin to `.block { page-break-inside: avoid; }` and let the layout engine to solve it by itself.